# How to send complex nested Json in body as http post request from Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to send a nested Json as a body in one of the HTTP post requests from the flutter app I had been working on. This is the JSON body I have to send to the server.

```
 {
    "title": "this is my test title",
    "description":"this is my test description",
    "images":[
        {
            "image":"mdNBqHlpws+IxE/vUbeQe6E/U+3/v9GNmYqhFaWTKSVDyzoC7fsrDlMSwBAobp73ZUMl5yGcg8Tsqq1CD/j8r5jETCXQii9RVDoJLe80yUk66FYJtyIpxntiSi1qBi8RzThIWklJ2a4QL5+x9x4NOpFbyil/yScTyqSjwTnyL8cA8jOMmxCv/vBSB89nPPyaPZTe66aUZ3Hvr3GQ7AOHvf773X+Nk0PbPzlU1umMTUe7m3Kq2lJHbd0a9Qp4lLOwymvQKKljFKK1EmJL4b/Ayq6Sw62BpPE3I+R0JV5D8qEnUti20zhrw6xEus8A8b2UJMmaL1ev4vhIztq1G/1oS8LLdDq4Gi93VpLkEz62fwswAPFnwbRmcGeKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
        }
         
    ]
}
```

I tried many methods that were available online to do it, but every time I'm getting a 500 error. Below is a class to convert it into JSON.

```
 class PostUpload_Request {
      final String? title;
      final String? description;
      final List<Image>? images;
    
      PostUpload_Request({this.title, this.description, this.images});
    
      factory PostUpload_Request.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    
        return PostUpload_Request(
            title: parsedJson['title'],
            description: parsedJson['description'],
            images: parsedJson['images']
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Image {
      Image({required this.image});
    
      final String? image;
    
      factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
        return Image(
            image:parsedJson['image'],
    
        );
      }
    
    }
```

I'm a newbie in a flutter. Kindly check my code.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
  images: parsedJson['images']
```

T0

```
parsedJson['images'].map((e) => e).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the JSON response, as you can see, the image property is a list, so make the 'images' a List as send (post) one as it is. First you define the list in the class (model) of the JSON response:

```
class Images {
  final String image;

  Images({this.image});

  factory Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Images(
      image: json['image'],
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the PostUploadRequest you define the list so you can send (post) it:

```
class PostUpload_Request {
      final String? title;
      final String? description;
      List<Images> image; //here you define that images is a list
    
      PostUpload_Request({this.title, this.description, this.images});
    
      factory PostUpload_Request.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
 /// IF IT DOESN"T WORK LIKE I SAID,TRY ADDING THESE LINES BELOW TO THE POST CLASS  
/// List<dynamic> images = json['image'];
/// List<Images> imageList = image.map((image) => Images.fromJson(image)).toList();
        return PostUpload_Request(
            title: parsedJson['title'],
            description: parsedJson['description'],
/// and instead of this below, you add: 
//     image: imageList,
            image: [{
                   image: parsedJson['image']
                  }]
        );
      }
    }
```

You wrap the the image attribute inside square brackets `[]` so it get's sent as a list.
Try this and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks, GrandMagus for your reply.  I have shared my model class. Kindly check it is right?

Comment: It gives an error. I need to convert my image file into base64 and then upload it to the server.                                                 PickedFile? imageFile =
                  await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera,
                      imageQuality: 80);
                  setState(() {
                    file = File(imageFile!.path);
                    final bytes = File(imageFile!.path).readAsBytesSync();
                    base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
                    image.add(base64Image);
                  });

Comment: Then that's a different kind of problem that is not related to the question at hand. Please try to search for the `base64 decoding in flutter` and try again.